# PHP - PDO like toolbox for HapiJS / Node

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, pdo, hapi.js

I am developing a HapiJS backend and was wondering if an PDO like toolbox exists that would take care of modulating MySQL queries.

Right now I am simply adding the string into the query string `... WHERE X = '"+someValue+"' AND ...` and I do not consider this being typesafe etc...

In PDO you can assign the values to the query which handles types automatically...

Answer (score 1):

node-mysql,sequlize js will solve the problem.